# How to show UIViewControllers UIView in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am making a little passcode thingy for my app, I like to present it in my AppDelegate method in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;`.

I created the PasscodeViewController in the Storyboard, because it is easier, now I try to present the UIView. The PasscodeViewController should be transparent because I like to blur the apps UIWindow behind it. This is what I tried:

```
PasscodeViewController *pcvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[self isiPad]?@"Main-iPad":@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PasscodeView"];
    [pcvc loadView];
    pcvc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.window addSubview:pcvc.view];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:pcvc.view];
```

But `pcvc` never shows up.

Does anyone know why or have a better way to show this `UIViewController` or its `UIView`?

Thanks, David

**Edit**
This is `[self isiPad];`

```
-(BOOL)isiPad {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not present `PasscodeViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method of Initial View Controller of Storyboard.

Comment: Because if another ViewController is on top of the initial ViewController the PasscodeViewController wont show.

Comment: You should try to do a presentModalViewController without animation. It's a good practice to avoid to manually add the view of a viewController as subview of the window or other viewControllers.